# Is it possible to set `matchpairs` in vim based on filetype?

Tags: vim, macvim

I want to set the following `matchpairs` option in vim only if filetype is PHP.

```
set matchpairs+==:;
```

Is it possible to do it?

I tried to read the documentation for `matchpairs` but it doesn't seem to mention any such option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to customize settings by filetype is using droping a file into your `ftplugin` folder of your runtime folder. Normally `~/.vim/ftplugin`

The file must be named as the file type, so if you were doing this for Ruby, you would have `~/.vim/ftplugin/ruby.vim`

Just make sure that your have support for filetypes

```
:filetype plugin on
```

And! Maybe instead of using `set` commands, you will want to use `setlocal` so the effects stays only within the current buffer.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your `.vimrc`:
`autocmd FileType php setlocal matchpairs+==:;`

But if you have more settings you want to set for a specific filetype, you should save them in `~/.vim/ftplugin/YOUR_LANGUAGE.vim` (without the `autocmd FileType YOUR_LANGUAGE` prefix).

Comment: Since it is appending to `matchpairs` setting, will the `matchpairs` setting be removed if I switch to a new file of different filetype?